# Shopify APIs - creating order without receiving payment from end-user

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

So we're building a buy-now-pay-later store module in our web-app that will be integrated into Shopify (via Shopify's Storefront APIs).

Our users should be able to make orders through our web app (without payment), and then someone on our end will be able to fulfill the order.

The user would then able to make their payment after the fact (via a custom payment implementation handled on our side), and then a webhook would just update the payment status from 'Pending Payment' to 'Complete' on shopify.

Is this possible via Shopify's APIs? We're trying to find a way to directly create an order without requiring payment, but our devs aren't having that much luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very much easy to do when you work with Draft Orders. That allows you to create a comprehensive near perfect order in the store. The main advantage is, you get define the payment using API calls. So you can convert this Draft Order to a real one, requiring a payment, when you wish to actually charge the customer, and you do that with code. They are sent an email with a link to a real checkout, allowing them to actually pay. You can also convert the Draft Order to a real order, without sending the customer the generated link to make a payment, and therefore, you can fulfill a real Order in the store, and get the customer to pay later, when you wish.